# Process is not found if opened until a lot of searches

Tags: python, windows, psutil

```
import psutil

name = "notepad.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name().lower() == name.lower():
        print("found")
    elif proc.name().lower() != name.lower():
        print("not found")
```

output:

```
not found
not found
not found
found
not found
not found
```

"notepad.exe" was open from the start and until the end of the script.

Comment: Not a regular `psutil` user, but it looks like it's iterating over all the processes -- there's other processes running on your computer, so this seems like expected behavior, unless I'm missing something. What is the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: the output I posted wouldn't be a big problem, but I had to remove a lot of "not found" prints, because there was like 20x more. Also it would be good to find the process instantly. (like if process is running only print "found")

Comment: The `elif` block is futile. Every time a process name doesn't match, you are printing 'not found'. There is no point to this. Even if there was, as you have just tested `proc.name().lower() == name.lower()` there would still be no point in now testing `proc.name().lower() != name.lower()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you could use `any()` rather than using a `for` loop:

```py
if any(proc.name().lower() == name.lower() for proc in psutil.process_iter()):
    print("found")
else
    print("not found")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as I wanted it to be. Could you explain me in short why and how did this work?

Comment: Under the hood, `any()` iterates over the processes from `process_iter()`. If their name matches the target name, we print `"found"`. Otherwise, we continue to the next process. **Only after we've looked at all the processes without finding a match** do we print out `"not found"`. See docs for [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Answer (score 0):

### psutil.process_iter() gives you an generator of all running processes.

Hi [whytfnotworking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19371257/whytfnotworking). Your code behaves as it should. Remember than, as the psutil.process_iter documentation says, it will iterates over all the running processes. In a typical machine you can have hundreds of them (I have at least 238 running right now). So, if you want to just get the one your'e interested in, you could simply remove the last two lines:

```py
import psutil

name = "notepad.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name().lower() == name.lower():
        print("found")
        break #This is for stop the iteration once found
```

Edit:

If you want to see when it's not found, then you could make use of an powerful, yet non popular feature of python loops: the *else* (yes, else in loops... python is amazing).

```py
import psutil

name = "notepad.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name().lower() == name.lower():
        print("found")
        break #This is for stop the iteration once found
else:
    print("not found") #It will get executed when the loop ends normally (not breaked)
```

Comment: This could work, but I want to have the "not found" print for debug purposes.